# Apache MINA Java TCP Client-Server Communication

Tags: apache-mina

i want co communicate TCP client server communication using apache mina.
can anyone give the code ?
i cant find it in any were....
google is failed to find it.
i want to send and recieve text messages via mina .
so please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple 
on the server side

```
 SocketConnectorConfig SOCKET_CONFIG = new SocketConnectorConfig();

        IoFilter charsetFilter = new ProtocolCodecFilter(
        new TextLineCodecFactory(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        SOCKET_CONFIG.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", charsetFilter);
theIoAcceptor.bind(new InetSocketAddress(thePort),
                      new TriggerReceiverHandler();
```

here ioAcceptor is of type `org.apache.mina.common.IoAcceptor` you can instantiate it by using `NioDatagramAcceptor`

`TriggerReceiverHandler` is the class that handles the messages and session related events. 
it needs to extend the `IoHandlerAdapter`.

This is for server. Similarly for client the only change is instead of IoAcceptor you use the IoConnector.

Here is an example, well explained too.
http://www.techbrainwave.com/?p=912